1ns pulse (comparator) 10ns delay
Given a 1.5 ns pulse, 3.3 V, how does one delay this pulse for a time in the range of 5 ns to 20 ns with maximum jitter 100 ps?
The solution needs to go between the output of a comparator (TI TLV360x) and the stop pin of a TDC (Time-to-Digital Converter) (TI TDC7200).
The TDC datasheet lists the measurement range as 12 ns to 500 ns, and precision 55ns.  We want to shift the range back to 0 or slightly before 0.
In this case a cable delay line is not an option.
We need to do this on the board, ideally in 1 or 2 IC's.

This sounds a bit like an X/Y problem to me. What do you actually want to achieve with that? Why do you need it?

A couple meters of coax?

Can you include a link to the TDC datasheet?

@ChesterGillon   I added the part number to the text.

Your TDC specs a minimum pulse width of 10ns, so a 1 ns pulse can't be used as input. And you still haven't given us any hint of the application, which drives the solution.

1ns at 3.3V is quite a narrow and strong pulse. Bandwidth of at least 500MHz is implied. While this isn't impossible, it is exceptional for what otherwise sounds like a LVCMOS signal. Would an LVDS or ECL solution be a consideration?

TI: These 'LS31 delay elements are intended to provide well-defined delays across both temperature and Vcc ranges. (2 × 6 ns, + others)

@greybeard, thank you.  got it.   I saw the SN74LS31 before I posted,  I haven't found a 3.3V equivalent.  Also it seems to be missing a diagram and without it, I am not sure how to understand their description of the timings.

It's for photon counting with a silicon photomultiplier.

Why do you need a TDC for photon counting?

@JohnDoty   For timing, for example fluorescent lifetime.   "Photon counting" in this application means counts with times.  Some instruments actually save the arrival time for each photon.   Another example is for quantum statistics, photon entanglement, delayed choice. etc etc.    For all of the above, it would be nice to get rid of the 12ns without having to use 8 meters of wire between the detector and the first amplifier.

OK, what's the drift time in your detector?

@JohnDoty   It's a soild state device, a silicon photomultiplier.

12 ns is only 2.4 m of LMR100 cable, which can be spooled up into a fairly tight area.  For what it is worth, I have seen kilometers of fiber spooled up in pulse timing applications to implement very precise delays.  A few meters of coax here seems very reasonable to me, and would have jitter that is hard to beat.

@DrM I know what it is, but how fast is it? I use SDDs for tagging photons, and they're fast, but not single digit nanosecond fast.

@JohnDoty  It has 100ps rise time.  There is a fast pulse output, 1.5ns, which can be made shorter with a little effort.  I think the rise time is sort of typical.  We have used avalanche diodes for pico second timing.

@user1850479  Yes cable is how we did it with phototubes in the 70's and 80's. The number 1.5 nsec/ft (for rg58) is with me forever.

The rise time is a pretty good indication of the drift time. And you don't want or need a narrow pulse, just a rise with low timing jitter. Over 50 years ago I did subnanosecond timing with vacuum PMTs and plastic scintillators. The pulses were quite a few nanoseconds long, but the edges were predictable.

To ask a recommendation for delay line implementation, you should specify the details beyond delay time range and jitter time parameters.
First, the delay lines can be analog or digital; delay time can be fixed or adjustable. Analog delay lines can by implemented with lumped or distributed elements, see also surface-acoustic-wave or magneto-strictive delay lines, each of which may be suitable or more often unsuitable for your purpose.
Digital delay lines can be blocking or non-blocking. Blocking DDLs are characterized by a dead time, when the input signal is blocked by processing the previous input. Non-blocking delay lines are typically tapped delay lines, where the output is taken from the corresponding tap.
While this taxonomy is evidently not the answer to your question, it provides you with necessary keywords for searches. Doing search, you may find the commercial device that suits your requirements; if not, you can return to electronics.SE with a question satisfying the community expectation for question clarity.

Per yours and others comments, I added more detail.  I thought delaying a 1ns, 3.3v pulse by 5ns to 20ns was fairly specific, but I should have added it needs to be a circuit element on a PCB.  I am sorry that your answer, while instructive, is not an answer to this question.   For background, there are few parts vendors still in the niche, and the parts I have found so far all seem to need a pulse as long as the desired delay.  I prefer to not have to stretch and then shorten the pulse for reasons of space and performance.

It may well be advantageous to filter the raw pulse, so you don't have to deal with as much bandwidth.  This spreads out (and delays!) the pulse, reducing its amplitude.  A comparator will be required to restore it to logic level.
If you can change to a higher voltage supply for the final avalanche stage, the higher amplitude, passed through the filter, might afford similar amplitude, reducing jitter due to the filter and comparator.  A comparator might not be required at all.  Mind that clamping would likely be required, if coincidence of photons produces a stacked pulse (longer duration and/or greater amplitude).
Or if it's a supply-discharge type avalanche device, merely increasing the node capacitance could extend pulse duration, again leaving more signal after the filter.  A compact PFN (pulse forming network) or (ceramic loaded) transmission line might afford a longer, squarer pulse, and likewise be a viable route to introduce delay, particularly with the reduced bandwidth.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Bandwidth is key, because for example, the number of stages for a lumped-element delay line grows quadratically with the bandwidth-delay ratio.  Reducing the bandwidth turns an at least inconvenient problem (spool of coax / huge board area snaking a delay trace around) to a compact one (few/dozens of chip components).

Good point, nice work.  We thought about it too.

You said you wanted something on a circuit board, but didn't disclose potential size limitations.
You can form a transmission line on a PCB. Passing it around in a spiral pattern and on several layers, it is possible to form a several meters long line in a rather small area such as 10×10 cm².
If you need something tunable, you can place some fast comparators at several points along the line, e.g. every nanosecond.

thank, it sounds like a neat technique, have you done this?  Anyway, 10cm is still pretty big.

@DrM I haven't done so for this purpose or pulse shape, but I have used transmission lines up to ~50 cm length on a regular FR4 PCB. The delay of digital edges scales as expected with the length and can be confirmed with an oscilloscope. The shape of the edge remains essentially undistorted on FR4 up to the frequency of interest, which was ~200MHz in my case. If you use 6 layers with the transmission line going in 3 levels, you need only ~1m per level. This could be feasibly packed into a 3x3 cm area I guess. The comparators and their supplies will eventually need more space.

Maybe a DS1100L "Timing Element". Can't handle 1 ns pulses, but neither can your TDC7200, so if that's a requirement you're already in trouble.

not an answer, it is a comment.   But anyway, as you hinted, latch and delay is the right way to go.  I will just have to tuck-up and do it.  I was resisting the space and component count and hoping for a single ic solution.

Well as it turns out, jitter for the ds1100l is 300ps.  The support engineer added that the market for these is getting smaller.
